# Cocos2d | Arc Enabled - Create a Singleton BaseLayer which manages the rest of the layers

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, singleton, automatic-ref-counting

Hope all is well. I have with me here a slightly complex, and mind boggling question, and desperately need your help. I am trying to setup a Cocos2d 2.x environment in an already established ARC based application, which entertains a third party library therefore some classes are ARC enabled and some others like Cocos2d classes, aren’t. Anyhow, the Cocos2d is functional thankfully but like my older ARC disabled Game Environments this code does not support SynthesizeSingleton.h, a class I was very fond of. Instead, I did some research and got hold on many ARC enabled singleton solutions, one of which is described in [this post](http://lukeredpath.co.uk/blog/2011/07/01/a-note-on-objective-c-singletons/).

In any case, I need to explain to you how I manage my game environment. Like Apple strongly recommends, the MVC pattern, I have my Models separate from the Views and Control helps connect everything. Similarly, the Views are all handled from one primary Scene, which contains the BaseLayer. All other layers are children to this BaseLayer, which in itself is a singleton, and therefore manages all other layers i.e. I have my only Singular Scene, it adds a BaseLayer and the BaseLayer adds all other Layers on the basis of their Z-Index or destroys them if not required. In all my non-ARC enabled projects, this works fine, but somehow the dispatch_once_t doesn't execute once, but always hence the instance is reset and the singleton fails to execute like promised. What should I do? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, this project and the GameScene in this [source code](http://www.apress.com/downloadable/download/sample/sample_id/640/) in chapter 8 helped me produce a very simple, yet not so tidy a solution:

the easiest solution was to:

`static MyBaseLayer *sharedMyBaseLayer = nil;`

Followed by,

```
+ (MyBaseLayer*)sharedMyBaseLayer
{
    NSAssert(sharedMyBaseLayer != nil, @"BaseLayer instance not yet initialised!");
    return sharedMyBaseLayer;
}
```

And then use the scene to init the layer where **sharedMyBaseLayer** instance is set:

```
+(CCScene *) scene

{
    CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];
    // 'layer' is an autorelease object.
    MyBaseLayer *layer = [MyBaseLayer node];

    // add layer as a child to scene
    [scene addChild: layer];

    // return the scene
    return scene;
}

-(id)init
{
    if(self = [super init])
    {
        sharedMyBaseLayer = self;
    }
    return self;
}
```

This gave me a beautiful singleton instance that is never reinitiated and serves my purpose well. However flawed for multiple threads, it is working damn fine for me. If any other ideas do come around, please do update me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the purpose of your singleton, but you create them like so (no global static variables):

```
+ (id)sharedManager
{
    static MyManager *sharedMyManager = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^
    {
        sharedMyManager = [[self alloc] init];
    });

    return sharedMyManager;
}
```

dispatch_once is thread safe. I think you are overthinking things. I really don't see what singletons have to do with MVC or why you are trying to do what your OP is stating.

The point of MVC is to have data (models), views (presentation), and controllers (the glue that ties them together) so that you can have a lot of code reuse. cocos2d is not built around this but even if you wanted to do it anyway, singleton's have nothing to do with that.

You can still separate model data and logic in a way that is can be reused in a non-cocos2d specific manner, but I don't see how a global layer accomplishes this.